# Is it possible to get Page Properties inside CQ dialog listener

Tags: dialog, adobe, listener, aem

I have a page at 
/content/admin/mycomp-test/testpage/jcr:content

property

```
name : validated
type : boolean
value : true
```

Is it possible to get the above property value inside CQ dialog's 
I tried the following code, but it;s not working.

```
<listeners jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
               beforesubmit="function(dialog) {

                var compPath = dialog.path;

                Resource res= resourceResolver.getResource(compPath);

                Node node = res.adaptTo(Node.class);

                var prop= node.getProperty('validated').getValue().getString(); 



                CQ.Ext.Msg.alert('valieded : ' + prop);
                    return false;

        }" />
}
```

Comment: You are trying to use java code in JS function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code will get you what you're asking for:

```
<listeners jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    beforesubmit="function(dialog) {
        var properties = CQ.shared.HTTP.eval(CQ.shared.HTTP.noCaching(dialog.path + '.-1.json'));
        var validated = properties.validated;

        CQ.Ext.Msg.alert('Validated: ' + validated);

    }" />
}
```

In my opinion, it's better to keep this type of JavaScript in an external file which would be included in a clientlib that only displays in edit mode. You can then call that method from within the dialog. For example:

```
beforesubmit="function(dialog){ foo.bar.baz(dialog); }"
```

If you're looking to validate user input, there are better ways. Explore the [Widgets API documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/widgets-api/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @EkUser, you are welcome. If I helped you, please consider accepting my answer as the correct answer.